# Can't recognize one character

Tags: kanji, hiragana

Can anyone please tell me what's the last character in the picture below? I can't recognize, it looks like hiragana but I don't know which one.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The character is が. Looking at the stroke order diagram: [image]

you can see that the writing tool has touched the writing surface when moving between the second and the third stroke.